dotnet build /P:PublishProfile to Linux App Service
I have the following command line
dotnet build "path to the project/MyProject.csproj" /P:DeleteExistingFiles=true /P:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=false /P:DeployOnBuild=true /P:PublishProfile=linux-publish-profile /P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /P:Configuration=Release /P:Username=$linux_user /P:Password=987lskdjfhw434k5hökjk345345k3j45

and the following publish profile
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>ZipDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <IsLinux>true</IsLinux>
    <ResourceId>/subscriptions/some subscription/resourceGroups/some-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/my-app</ResourceId>
    <ResourceGroup>some-resource-group</ResourceGroup>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>true</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>http://my-app-stage.azurewebsites.net</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <PublishProvider>AzureWebSite</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <ProjectGuid>b6eccaec-519f-41b2-a3ee-d7bdb6bbf440</ProjectGuid>
    <PublishUrl>https://my-app-stage.scm.azurewebsites.net/</PublishUrl>
    <UserName>$linux-user</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>true</_SavePWD>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

The deployment does work with this publish profile from VS 2022.
But not as a command line.
The command line does work with publish profiles to windows app services.

Are trying to deploy your .net App to Azure Linux Web app using Zip deployment?

Are you Using .net core or >net Framework?

I created a sample project and deployed it to Azure App Service via Command line.

Instead of using dotnet build, use dotnet msbuild for more control and flexibility in complex build and deployment tasks.

I referred this Msdoc and used the below command to deploy the app.


dotnet publish -c Release
dotnet msbuild "path/to/your/project/MyLinuxApp.csproj" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="path/to/linuxapp18.PublishSettings" /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /p:UserName=$LINUX_USER /p:Password=$LINUX_PASSWORD


In your .csproj file add runtime identifier (linux-x64) to deploy the app to Azure App Service (Linux).

  <RuntimeIdentifiers>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>

.csproj file :
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>


Output after deployment:


Unfortunately it doesn't work.
What exactly is VS doing when deploying to linux app service?
Because when pushing Publish button the VS does publish everything.

I hope you added the runtime identifier in your .csprojfile as it is necessary for deploying the app to Linux.
When Visual Studio deploys the app, it performs several steps: restoring dependencies, building the project, packaging it, and deploying it, including necessary configuration settings.
